# JQuery multiply and add

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have some numbers that I want to multiply and add.

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
var c = 2;
var d = 3;
```

I want to sum b and c then multiply that by a, then add d. Easy right?

If if were a normal equation the formula would look like: (a * (b  + c) + d)

But how do I do that in JQuery?

(Note: the reason for JQuery is that I'll be getting these numbers from fields and divs... and placing a total elsewhere, etc.)

Comment: jQuery is 100% Javascript. You can use this as usual after getting your values via the element selectors. - Please specify your question further if you need more help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default script language does not know type as `int` or `float`. So you can  fix that by multiplying 1 to the value you expect to be a number.

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
var c = 2;
var d = 3; 

var total = a*1 * (b*1 + c*1) + d*1;
```

Comment: I'd wager that most of the answers here would work... but this one wins for simplicity. :)

Answer (score 4):

convert your value into float or integer first before you do calculation. Example:

```
var a = parseFloat($(this).val());
var b = parseInt($("#b").attr("data"));

var c = (a+10)*b;
$("#result").text(c.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just store the values in variables before you apply them to the equation:

```
var a = +$("#input1")[0].value;
var b = +$("#input2")[0].value;
var c = +$("#input3")[0].value;
var d = +$("#input4")[0].value;

$("#output")[0].value = a*(b+c) + d;
```

The plus sign before the jquery function is there to force the string value into a Number value.

Answer (score 2):

Correct JQuery is 100% javascript.

Although, worth mentioning just use parseint() for the values that you get from text field

Answer (score 1):

You can still do the calculation using normal javascript, just refer to the contents using jQuery selectors if necessary.