# Need Help Calculating in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with my calculations. I know my code is terrible as i am only a beginner but I need it to work. Pleas don't complain and tell me that there is more efficient ways to do it. If it is that much of a problem then fix but bleas don't tell me how bad i am... i already know. Can you just help me with my JavaScript. I also need a running total to appear in the grey div.

**THE ALERTS ARE TO BE DELETED**

We were supposed to make a web ordering service. 
**PLEASE HELP IT'S FOR AN ASSIGNMENT!** (CODE IS NOT FOR ASSINGMENT... THE ASSGNMENT IS A REPORT SO YOU WON'T BE MAKING ME CHEAT.) Think of it as helping someone who is learning.

Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/gefxbvhr/

HTML

```
<title>Test Practice V3 - Order</title>
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
<div id="ocontainer">
    <div id="buttons">
        <div id="homebutton">
          <a href="index.html">home</a>
        </div>
        <div id="menubutton">
          <a href="menu.html">menu</a>
        </div>
        <div id="orderbutton">
          <a href="order.html">order</a>
        </div>
        <div id="fbackbutton">
        <a href="feedback.html">feedback</a>    
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="content"> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <form id="chipform">
        <legend><b>Chips:</b></legend>
        <select  id="chipselectbox" onchange="calculateTotal()">
            <option value="None">Select Size</option>
            <option value="XS">X-Small ($2)</option>
            <option value="S">Small ($3)</option>
            <option value="M">Medium ($4)</option>
            <option value="L">Large ($5)</option>
            <option value="XL">X-Large ($6)</option>
        </select>
    </form>  
    <br>
    <br>
   <center>
   <table>
   <tr class="cboxtable">
    <th> </th>
    <th><b>Snack:</b></th>      
    <th><b>Price:</b></th>
    <th><b>Quantity:</b></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="calamari" onClick="document.getElementById('calamariqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Calamari (10 Pieces)</td>
    <td>$6.50</td>      
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="calamariqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="garlicball" onClick="document.getElementById('garlicballqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Chicken Garlic Ball</td>
    <td>$6.50</td>      
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="garlicballqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cnugget" onClick="document.getElementById('cnuggetqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Chicken Nugget</td>
    <td>$1.50</td>      
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="cnuggetqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="dsl" onClick="document.getElementById('dslqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Dim Sum (Large)</td>
    <td>$2.00</td>      
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="dslqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="dss" onClick="document.getElementById('dssqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Dim Sum (Small)</td>
    <td>$1.20</td>      
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden"> 
        <input type="text" size="10" id="dssqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="bbq" onClick="document.getElementById('bbqqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Family BBQ Chicken</td>
    <td>$12.50</td>     
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="bbqqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="bbqccg" onClick="document.getElementById('bbqccgqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Family BBQ Chicken + Chips + Gravy</td>
    <td>$16.50</td>     
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="bbqccgqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="fburger" onClick="document.getElementById('fburgerqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Fish Burger</td>
    <td>$6.00</td>      
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="fburgerqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="fcake" onClick="document.getElementById('fcakeqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Fish Cake</td>
    <td>$2.00</td>      
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="fcakeqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="flakeb" onClick="document.getElementById('flakebqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Flake (Battered)</td>
    <td>$1.50</td>      
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="flakebqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="flakec" onClick="document.getElementById('flakecqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Flake (Crumbed)</td>
    <td>$1.50</td>      
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="flakecqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="kabana" onClick="document.getElementById('kabanaqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Kabana</td>
    <td>$2.50</td>      
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="kabanaqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ppup" onClick="document.getElementById('ppupqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Pluto Pup/Dagwood Dog</td>
    <td>$3.00</td>      
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="ppupqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="pcake" onClick="document.getElementById('pcakeqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Potato Cake </td>
    <td>$1.00</td>      
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="pcakeqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="seas" onClick="document.getElementById('seasqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Sea Scallop</td>
    <td>$2.00</td>      
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="seasqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sfstick" onClick="document.getElementById('sfstickqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Seafood Stick</td>
    <td>$1.50</td>
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="sfstickqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sproll" onClick="document.getElementById('sprollqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Spring Roll (Large)</td>
    <td>$2.50</td>      
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="sprollqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cboxtable">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="wht" onClick="document.getElementById('whtqty').style.visibility='visible';">
    </form></td>
    <td>Whiting (Crumbed)</td>
    <td>$1.50</td>
    <td>
    <form style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="whtqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onChange="calculateTotal()">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </center>
<br>


<div id="orderprices">

</div><br>
<center>
<form>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</center>





    </div>


    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-image:url(../5%20February/Images/Water%20Image.jpg);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
#container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #333;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding:20px;
}
#ocontainer {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #333;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding:20px;
}
#buttons {
    height:50px;
    width:85%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#homebutton {
    height: 100%;
    width: 23.5%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-right:2%;
}
#menubutton {
    height:100%;
    width:23.5%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-right:2%;
}
#orderbutton {
    height:100%;
    width:23.5%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-right:2%;
}
#fbackbutton {
    height:100%;
    width:23.5%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:black;
    font-size:18px;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:0px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;   
}
#homebutton:hover {
    background-color:#00BBFF;
}
#menubutton:hover {
    background-color:#00BBFF;
}
#orderbutton:hover {
    background-color:#00BBFF;
}
#fbackbutton:hover {
    background-color:#00BBFF;
}
#feedback {
    padding:10px;
}
#content {
    width: 95%;
    height: 1000px;
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-size:16px;
}
#cboxform {
    width: 39%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    line-height: 26px;
    height: 550px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#quantityform {
    width: 47.5%;
    float: right;
    height: 550px;
}
#quantityform br {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#pricediv {
    float: left;
    line-height: 26px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 550px;

}
#chipform {
    width:100%;

}
#orderprices
{
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#666;
    height:15px;
    color:#FFF;
    width:50%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto
}
table {
    alignment-adjust:central;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function getChipPrice()
{
    var chip_prices= new Array();
    chip_prices["None"]=0;
    chip_prices["XS"]=2;
    chip_prices["S"]=3;
    chip_prices["M"]=4;
    chip_prices["L"]=5;
    chip_prices["XL"]=6; 

    var shopChipPrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["chipform"];

    var selectedChip = theForm.elements["chipselectbox"];


    shopChipPrice = chip_prices[select.value];
    alert(shopChipPrice);

    return shopChipPrice;
}


function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


function snackPriceCalculate() {

    var snack1 = document.getElementById('calamariqty');
    var snack2 = document.getElementById('cnuggetqty');
    var snack3 = document.getElementById('dslqty');
    var snack4 = document.getElementById('dssqty');
    var snack5 = document.getElementById('bbqqty');
    var snack6 = document.getElementById('bbqccgqty');
    var snack7 = document.getElementById('fburgerqty');
    var snack8 = document.getElementById('fcakeqty');
    var snack9 = document.getElementById('flakebqty');
    var snack10 = document.getElementById('flakecqty');
    var snack11 = document.getElementById('garlicballqty');
    var snack12 = document.getElementById('kabanaqty');
    var snack13 = document.getElementById('pcakeqty');
    var snack14 = document.getElementById('ppupqty');
    var snack15 = document.getElementById('seasqty');
    var snack16 = document.getElementById('sfstickqty');
    var snack17 = document.getElementById('sprollqty');
    var snack18 = document.getElementById('whtqty');
    var totalPrice=0;

    if (parseInt(snack1.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack1.value)*6.50;}
    if (parseInt(snack2.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack2.value)*6.50;}
    if (parseInt(snack3.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack3.value)*2.00;}
    if (parseInt(snack4.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack4.value)*2.50;}
    if (parseInt(snack5.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack5.value)*1.20;}
    if (parseInt(snack6.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack6.value)*12.50;}
    if (parseInt(snack7.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack7.value)*16.50;}
    if (parseInt(snack8.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack8.value)*6.00;}
    if (parseInt(snack9.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack9.value)*2.00;}
    if (parseInt(snack10.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack10.value)*1.50;}
    if (parseInt(snack11.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack11.value)*1.50;}
    if (parseInt(snack12.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack12.value)*2.50;}
    if (parseInt(snack13.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack13.value)*3.00;}
    if (parseInt(snack14.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack14.value)*1.00;}
    if (parseInt(snack15.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack15.value)*2.00;}
    if (parseInt(snack16.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack16.value)*1.50;}
    if (parseInt(snack17.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack17.value)*2.50;}
    if (parseInt(snack18.value)>0) {totalPrice = parseInt(snack18.value)*1.50;}
    alert(totalPrice);
    snackPriceCalculate();
    getChipPrice();

}

function calculateTotal()
{

    var orderPrice = snackPriceCalculate() + getChipPrice();
    alert("I am an alert box!");

    var totaldiv = document.getElementById('orderprices');
    totaldiv.style.display='block';
    totaldiv.innerHTML = "Total Price For your order $"+orderPrice;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var totaldiv = document.getElementById('orderprices');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: I suggest if you'd like help with your assignment, that you make it clear what the expected and actual results are. Currently as written, the question expects that we infer the problem and go from there. For instance, you say `"Can you just help me with my JavaScript. I also need a running total to appear in the grey div."` - help you with what exactly, and in addition to _what_? What is your problem calculating the running total? Do you not understand what it is? Do you get the wrong result? Do you not know where to start? Imagine reading your question with 0 knowledge of the assignment. :)

Comment: The totals don't calculate properly in the function calculateTotal() and i don't think that the function getChipprice() is working.

Comment: I want a working running total to be in the grey div in white text. If you look at the js fiddle you will see what I mean about the grey div

Comment: you have to tell us where to start to look into your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off I'd make all the inputs where you enter the quantity type="number" so that it can only accept a number and not just any text. example:

```
<input type="number" size="10" id="calamariqty" onChange="calculateTotal()">
```

also in your < select > use the prices as the value like this:

```
<select  id="chipselectbox" onchange="calculateTotal()">
    <option value="0">Select Size</option>
    <option value="2.00">X-Small ($2)</option>
    <option value="3.00">Small ($3)</option>
    <option value="4.00">Medium ($4)</option>
    <option value="5.00">Large ($5)</option>
    <option value="6.00">X-Large ($6)</option>
</select>
```

rather than XS or M etc.

then under a function called by the quantity input onchange, for each snack put something like this:

```
function calculateTotal() {
  var chips = document.getElementById("chipselectbox").value;

  if ($('#calamari').attr('checked')) {
    var quantity1 = $('#calamariqty').val();
    var price1 = 6.50;
    var snack1 = quantity1*1 * price1*1;
  } else {
    var snack1 = 0;
  }
  if ($('#garlicball').attr('checked')) {
    var quantity2 = $('#garlicballqty').val();
    var price2 = 6.50;
    var snack2 = quantity1*1 * price1*1;
  } else {
    var snack2 = 0;
  }

  //and so on ...
}
```

see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035788/jquery-multiply-and-add) to see why we do var*1 for multiplying vars.

and after all that, we add the snack1, snack2, etc variables together to get total and display the total in the orderprices div. this can be at the end of the same function as the other stuff:

```
var total = chips*1 + snack1*1  + snack2*1 + snack3*1 + //and so on ...
document.getElementById("orderprices ").innerHTML = "Total: $" + total + "0";
```

so the two functions you have are replaced by this one function we made:

```
function calculateTotal() {
  var chips = document.getElementById("chipselectbox").value;

  if ($('#calamari').attr('checked')) {
    var quantity1 = $('#calamariqty').val();
    var price1 = 6.50;
    var snack1 = quantity1*1 * price1*1;
  } else {
    var snack1 = 0;
  }
  if ($('#garlicball').attr('checked')) {
    var quantity1 = $('#garlicballqty').val();
    var price1 = 6.50;
    var snack1 = quantity1*1 * price1*1;
  } else {
    var snack2 = 0;
  }
  //and so on ...

  var total = chips*1 + snack1*1  + snack2*1 + snack3*1 + //and so on ...  ;
  document.getElementById("orderprices ").innerHTML = "Total: $" + total + "0";
}
```

I hope this works because I never actualy tested this. also if you are doing it this way, you don't need your inputs and stuff in all those forms just keep the id's the same on the inputs.